# наложение border css

Tags: html, css

```css
body, html, h1, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.circlewrap {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
}
.circlewrap .text {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: right;
}
.circlewrap .text h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 6px;
}
.circlewrap .text p {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 6px;
}
.circlewrap .h-wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 46px/50px;
  border-top-left-radius: hidden;
}
.circlewrap .h-wrap .circle {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.circlewrap .h-wrap .circle .c-cont {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.circlewrap .h-wrap .circle .c-cont img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
.circlewrap .h-wrap .hidden {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="circlewrap">
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Анализ конкурентной среды</h1>
                <p>Проводится детальный анализ ТОПА по продвигаемым запросам и сайтам конкурентов</p>
            </div>
            <div class="h-wrap">
                <div class="circle">
                    <div class="c-cont"><img src="img/x1.png"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden">
                    <p>текс текс текст</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    
    </main>
</body>
```

Имеется круг с серой границей. Хочу, чтобы при наведении на него справа появлялся блок. Но не могу понять как наложить бордер одного блока на другой. Постоянно отличается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у меня вышло вот-так

```css
body, html, h1, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.circlewrap {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  width: 90%;
  height: 99px;
}
.circlewrap .text {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: right;
}
.circlewrap .text h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 6px;
}
.circlewrap .text p {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 6px;
}
.circlewrap .h-wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50px/50px;
  border-left: none;
  height:100px;
}
.circlewrap .h-wrap .circle {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.circlewrap .h-wrap .circle .c-cont {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.circlewrap .h-wrap .circle .c-cont img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
.circlewrap .h-wrap .hidden {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="circlewrap">
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Анализ конкурентной среды</h1>
                <p>Проводится детальный анализ ТОПА по продвигаемым запросам и сайтам конкурентов</p>
            </div>
            <div class="h-wrap">
                <div class="circle">
                    <div class="c-cont"><img src="img/x1.png"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden">
                    <p>текс текс текст</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    
    </main>
</body>
```

поправил

Comment: может в браузере дело, но у меня отчетливо видится несоответствие границ примерно на 1-2 пикселя

Comment: поправил добавил высоту для класа .h-wrap и  border-left: none;